# NodeJS function parameter checking with assertions

Tags: javascript, node.js, assertions

NodeJS' dynamic typing is fun and all but given a function I'd like to get some feedback during development whether what I'm passing is in fact going to produce anything meaningful.

In C# I would do: `Debug.Assert(complexType.Title.length <= 10)` (such statements would not be included when compiled in release mode)

I found that for example Chai could do exactly this. However this is a BDD / TDD framework and I plan on putting this in production code, not in tests.

```
function doSomething(complexType) {
    expect(complexType.title).to.be.a('string');
}
```

I read that this could be compiled out with Uglify to more closely reflect `Debug.Assert` behaviour.

Is this a good idea? Or does NodeJS have 'real' assertions?

Comment: See: http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html

Comment: That is also intended for UnitTests. I want to know if it is a good idea to put such assertions in production code.

Comment: here is an example of nodejs code that uses `assert` in production: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L150

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea: it will slow down your code and after it has been properly tested during dev you should be reasonably sure the types are correct. If you need validation is another kind of task and there are different libraries for it

Comment: Yup, but `Uglify` should be able to take care of that...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409339/how-do-i-implement-assertions-in-javascript

Comment: I doubt assertions would noticeably slow down any code. Duck typing makes assertions even more useful. After all, you can still have bugs after testing...

Comment: `NodeJS' dynamic typing is fun and all ... `. My thoughts exactly. Swords always have two sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in [assert](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) template for assertion testing.
You can also use the built-in `arguments` object to test the arguments you receive to the function. Here's an example:

```
var assert = require('assert');

var doSomething () {
 if (arguments.length > 0) { // And you might even not need the if clause here...
  assert.equal(typeof arguments[0], 'string');
 }
}

doSomething('This is my title');
doSomething(1); // This will trigger the assert
```

Plus, there's more stuff you can do with the built-in `arguments` object but I guess the OP is more about the assert functionality.

Comment: You probably mean `assert.equal` instead of `assert.notEqual`.