# How do I implement assertions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, assertion

I'd like to use assertions to check for invalid parameters in my private methods (and others that should only be called internally). I'd prefer:

- A failed assertion terminates the program, or at least stops my automated tests. `console.assert()` doesn't appear to do this.
- Assertions can be stripped out during production deployment (I'm using Grunt).
- A very minimal solution (shouldn't need a library to do this).

EDIT:
I'm not trying to test anything here. If my motivation for doing this is unclear, check out CC2 or Clean Code or the Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)

Comment: 1. Why are you testing private methods? 2. **Why would you put tests inside actual code?** 3. Why not use a testing library? Feels like you're solving the wrong problem here. I bet your real problem is how to test your code properly given some situation you haven't mentioned.

Comment: this might be relevant to your concern http://philipwalton.com/articles/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Assertions are not just for tests. They serve a complementary role to practices such as exception handling and logging, and are promoted in many programming books such as CC2.

Comment: @Daniel_L Thanks Daniel, but I'm not trying to test these methods. I'm looking to use assertions as "executable documentation" to catch developer mistakes within my code base. I have unit tests in place separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like?

```
const assert = env === "production"
    ? () => {}
    : (test, msg) =>  {
        if (!test) throw new Error(`assertion failed: ${msg}`);
      };

// ...

function foo(param) {
    assert(typeof param === "number", "param is a Number");
}
```

Comment: Nice, this meets all of my criteria! I'll accept, but bonus points if anyone can suggest a way to also drop the call statements during minification.